# Is it possible with HTTP to identify that someone come from a redirect 301?

Tags: http, redirect

I have two website A and B.
I will close the first website and redirect all trafic toward B with 301 redirection. 
I would like to identify on B the trafic that come from A thank to this redirection.

But I can't put a tracker on the URL. How I can do that in a different way ?

Thank you all

Comment: ¿Identifying them to do what?

Comment: to prevent them that the url change

Answer (score 1):

You can get the url of the page (from where the form data is posted to the current page) by using-

```
$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

But this can't be trusted completely cause the 'http header' informations can be changed or hacked or the user may use proxy server.

Comment: Sorry, Because it's a redirect 301, the referer can't be the site A according to site B.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in javascript  i n Site B

`document.referrer` will return the referring url to this address.